# What happen with the Yellow Ring after the Green Lantern movie?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, green-lantern-2011

In the *Green Lantern* 2011 movie, an extraterrestrial Green Lantern asked the guardians to make him a yellow Ring powered by fear. While this ring wasn't used in the movie, it's fate is not stated further.

Was it destroyed? Or it was keep for some reason?

Comment: Did you not see that addon after the credits?  It shows exactly what happened to the Yellow Ring.

Comment: @BBlake No, I did not know there's was something to watch for after the credits.

Comment: @DavRob60 Pro Tip: If you're watching a comic-book movie, there's always something after the credits.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Last time I stayed for the whole credit just in case there was a post-credit scene, it was for "X-Men: First Class". It was a wasteful use of my time and I though it was now out of fashion.

Comment: @DavRob60 Even without the extra scene, watching the credits just for the awesome 60's graphics was enough for me, lol. And NOT having something after the credits is almost as shocking now a days.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Well, my wife won't agree with you.

Comment: Heh, we try not to mention X-Men First Class... ever... again...

Comment: FYI, the extraterrestrial Green Lantern is [Sinestro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinestro).

Comment: @BBlake What was wrong with it? I thought it was awesome.

Comment: Of all 5 of the X-Men movies of recent years it would be at the bottom of my list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spoilers to follow:

> Obviously, the guardians or whoever were going to keep the ring until Parallax was defeated.  However, they held onto the ring after that.  A scene after the ending credits shows Sinestro taking the yellow ring.  He removes his own green ring and puts on the yellow.  His entire suit changes to yellow.  Then he looks outward past the camera and you see his eyes are yellow as well.