# Where to check if a Movie has a post-credit scene without being spoiled?

Tags: movie, online-resources

I recently [missed some information](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5970/what-happen-with-the-yellow-ring-after-the-green-lantern-movie) because I did not watch a movie until the end of the credits.

I usually don't search on-line about a movie before watching it because I fear being spoiled. So, is there any resource I could safely check to know if a movie has a [Post-credits scene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-credits_scene)?

Comment: I suspect this will get close votes for being off-topic, but I think Sci-fi and Comic Book movies use these more often than other genres.  As such, I think such a resource would be especially helpful for users of this site.

Comment: @Keen There is other genres of movies?

Comment: Yes of course!  Have you forgotten about fantasy?

Comment: Personally, I wish movies would stop doing this.

Comment: I love when movies do it, lol. makes you wait in suspence!

Comment: I usually wait for the end of the credits anyway. Not that I would read them, but this is the time look at whoever you came with and form an opinion about the movie, and it's much easier to get out of the door later.

Comment: This is an example of why Movies.SE beta needs to come out of beta. It's a great "movies" question, but let's face it it's got nothing whatsoever to do with Sci-Fi, notwithstanding the attempts above :)

Comment: @MarkBeadles *Ferris Bueller's Day Off* is a comedy movie with a excellent post-credit scene, and it's the oldest movie I **remember** that uses such feature. (I may be wrong ... ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of times there will be a note in [IMDB](http://imdb.com) for a particular movie.  Unfortunately, I've found that about half the time it does list one, there is spoiler information in it.  But I think the best place to check is [MediaStinger](http://www.mediastinger.com/).  You can usually see here whether a movie has a stinger or coda (post or during credits extras) without getting them spoiled.  Just don't go into the movie's description (this does contain spoilers).  Just look at the summaries on the intro page.